# Is simulated annealing a kind of monte carlo method?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I am recently investigate some algorithms about optimization. I found a really interesting algorithm called simulated annealing. Base on what I understand, our initial point becomes a distribution instead of an actual point. It also relate to initial "temperature" but the main idea is "cool down". Which is try some case that "shifting" when you reach the local optimization. So that it can overcome the local optimum trap. I am wondering is the simulated annealing is also one kind of Monte Carlo method. The difference is Monte Carlo works globally and the simulated annealing works locally. Is my thought correct?

Comment: And what meanings did your research find for "Monte Carlo method" & what does that say about the answer?

Answer (score 1):

No, [annealing](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/) is not a type of Monte Carlo method, but your comparison isn't silly.  Annealing *is* probabilistic, but in a way that doesn't quite fit Monte Carlo's characteristics.

The main difference is the definition of the distribution during the process.  Monte Carlo identifies solutions by empirically simulating a distribution.  Annealing *changes* the distribution definition as it searches, gradually putting tighter restrictions on the probabilistic definition of "neighbor" for each state transition.

You may be somewhat distracted by the common illustrations of annealing, as the concept is often applied, in parallel, as a local resolution method to each pixel of an image.  This *is* a local application to which Monte Carlo doesn't apply well -- again, your thinking may well be accurate for what you have in mind, even if it's not purely correct in a formal sense.

Comment: Thanks for the respond. I am going to implement simulated annealing. Hopefully the implementation can help me classify them more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Going to disagree with the other answers here.  Simulated annealing (Metropolis-Hastings algorithm [1953]) is very much a Monte Carlo method.  Heck, Metropolis gave this class of methods the *name* "Monte Carlo methods".

Answer (score 0):

Except for the fact, that both methods use (pseudo) random numbers (and are therefore stochastic algorithms) they are very different:

- Monte-Carlo tests unrelated more or less equally distributed points in the solution space.
- Simulated Annealing starts with a point and creates a path through the solution space by altering the latest point. Depending on the current "temperature", the difference the altering makes and a random number the new point is accepted or the old point is kept. This approach works for solution spaces where good solutions tend to be surrounded by other good solutions. By gradually reducing the "temperature" one hopes to force the algorithm to bring the current point into better and better areas of the solution space.